# Why does using the RegEx /(?<=]),(?=(L|M|J|V))/gi with the JS split method give me this result?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

The title explains my problem. I don't understand why using the RegEx `/(?<=]),(L|M|J|V)/gi` with the JS `split()` method on a string gives me an unexpected result.

Using said RegEx results in:

```
[
'Lunes[9:00-13:00,14:00-16:00]',
  'M',
  'Martes[19:00-3:00]',
  'M',
  'Miercoles[19:00-21:00,0:00-3:30]',
  'J',
  'Jueves[6:00-8:00,8:30-10:30,16:00-20:05]' 
]
```

instead of:

```
[
  'Lunes[9:00-13:00,14:00-16:00]',
  'Martes[19:00-3:00]',
  'Miercoles[19:00-21:00,0:00-3:30]',
  'Jueves[6:00-8:00,8:30-10:30,16:00-20:05]' 
]
```

My code:

```
    const pattern = /(?<=]),(?=(l|m|j|v))/gi;
    const myString = "Lunes[9:00-13:00,14:00-16:00],Martes[19:00-3:00],Miercoles[19:00-21:00,0:00-3:30],Jueves[6:00-8:00,8:30-10:30,16:00-20:05]";
    const myArray = myString.split(pattern);
    console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the capture group in the lookahead, which you can omit
and use a character class instead of an alternation `[lmjv]`

```js
const pattern = /(?<=]),(?=[lmjv])/gi;
const myString = "Lunes[9:00-13:00,14:00-16:00],Martes[19:00-3:00],Miercoles[19:00-21:00,0:00-3:30],Jueves[6:00-8:00,8:30-10:30,16:00-20:05]";
const myArray = myString.split(pattern);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to escape the `]` in the lookbehind?  E.g. use: `(?<=\])`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think you have to do that https://regex101.com/r/A5H6jM/1 The code probably wouldn't have worked if we had too.

Comment: @losocio ... changing the capturing group ... `(?=(l|m|j|v))` ... within the lookahead into a non-capturing normal group ... `(?=(?:l|m|j|v))` ... via `?:` would have helped too, thus the before captured string will not anymore be part of the split result. But of cause using the character class is the best solution for it expresses far better the semantics.

Comment: That's right a `]` doesn't need to be escaped but `[` always needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Your exact problem may be lookbehinds are not being supported.  I would suggest a regex find all approach here:

```js
var myString = "Lunes[9:00-13:00,14:00-16:00],Martes[19:00-3:00],Miercoles[19:00-21:00,0:00-3:30],Jueves[6:00-8:00,8:30-10:30,16:00-20:05]";
var matches = myString.match(/\b[LMJVSD][a-z]+\[.*?\]/g);
console.log(matches);
```

The regex character class `\b[LMJVSD][a-z]+` covers Lunes through Domingo (Monday through Sunday).

Comment: This is a good aproach aswell, I just dont need weekends so /\b[LMJV][a-z]+\[.*?\]/g it is